# Problem In Storing The User's Data/Settings In The JSON File In WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have one WPF application. There is one dropdown for the language in it. By default, The user will get the `English` language as selected.

But when the user will change the language to `German` and then closes the application and re-opens it, Then the user should get the `German` language as selected. But in my case, The user was getting `English` as selected all the times.

So to do this, I have added code to save the language preference in the json file. Here is my code.

```
string strExecutingFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string strPreferencesFilePath = Path.Combine(strExecutingFolder, gblStrPreferencesFileName);

//SERIALIZE MODEL
string strPreferencesJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objPreferencesModel);

//SAVE JSON IN FILE
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPreferencesJSON))
{
    File.WriteAllText(strPreferencesFilePath, strPreferencesJSON);
}
```

The code is working fine in the local environment. But when I am making the `.msi` by using Wix and doing the same case, I am not seeing any reflection. The user is still not getting the previously selected language when he/she reopens the application.

Don't know why but its working in the local environment (Running project from visual studio by pressing CTRL+F5).

Comment: When you install an app, it is usually to programs. You can't just write to folders in there from a running app because that'd be a security malware hole.  This is why they created appdata. You should use that.